# realize parameter change after reboot in ESP wifi (Lua)

Tags: lua

I want to change the behaviour of my ESP module if some of my parameter was changed and then was restarted. I mean something like this.

> if (????) then
>       print ("default value") else
>       print ("modified value") end

First I thought of writing a flag into a file, but it causes error during boot if it is not existing yet.
Any better idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store values beyond reboot you have to store them in some non-volatile memory. So using a file is a good way as you already suggested.

Unfortunately you did not provide the error message you get when it is not existing yet and you did not say if the flag or the file does not exist.

What you have to do is handling the error. So if your file does not exist ask the user to create a new one or create a file with default content from your program.
Same goes with the flag. If the file does not contain a flag yet, use a default value or ask the user to give one.

It's not bad or wrong to get errors as long learn from them or handle them properly.

`io.open(filename[,mode])` returns `nil` plus an error message in case of an error.
So simply do something like:

```
local fileName = "C:\\superfile.txt"
local fileHandle, errorMsg = io.open(fileName)
if not fileHandle then
  print("File access error: ", errorMsg)
  -- add some error handling here
end
```

So in case you don't have that file you'll get

**File access error:   C:\superfile.txt: No such file or directory**

Comment: So if your file does not exist ask the user to create a new oneUnfortunazely

Comment: "So if your file does not exist ask the user to create a new one" Unfortunately it is not so simple. As it was mentioned in the title the question is about an ESP micro wifi board. If a parameter modification takes place via wifi communication, modified but autonomous behaviour is expected after rebooting.

Comment: @steve Well user interaction is just one general option. I also suggested to use hard coded default values which of course is more suitable for an embedded system. One way or another you have to handle file errors to resolve the exceptional situation.